conflicting hyperref and tikz in section title
The following code produces plenty of error messages, starting with "Argument of \pgfutil@in@@ has an extra }", when I uncomment \usepackage{hyperref}.
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{wall}=[line width=0.6pt]
\newcommand{\abc}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\protect\draw[wall] (0,0)--(0.2,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\section{The title includes \abc}
\end{document}

Could anyone help me to resolve the issue?

put \protect in front of \abc not in front of \draw

you also need a % after the { (unless you intent that \abc always adds a space before the tikz)

@DavidCarlisle Does not help, but possibly I put \protect in a wrong way. Could you, please, write how exactly this line should be modified?

\section{The title includes \protect\abc} is what @DavidCarlisle meant.

@Skillmon This produces 9 error messages for this line, starting with
! Argument of \tikz@style@parseA has an extra }.\par \section{The title includes \protect\abc}
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@style@parseA was complete.\par \section{The title includes \protect\abc}
! Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@@ProtectSpacesFi was complete.\par \section{The title includes \protect\abc}

Please note that \tikzstyle is deprecated. Have a look in the tikz user guide for \tikzset

You could use \texorpdfstring provided by hyperref to tell hyperref what to do with \abc if encountered.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{wall/.style={line width=0.6pt}}
\newcommand{\abc}
  {%
    \texorpdfstring
      {\tikz\draw[wall] (0,0) -- (0.2, 0.2);}%
      {<abc>}%
  }

\begin{document}
\section{The title includes \protect\abc}
\end{document}

(you still need \protect here to prevent \abc from exploding in the moving argument)

Thank you, this compiles! However if I draw two lines:
{%     \texorpdfstring       {\tikz\draw[wall] (0,0) -- (0.2, 0.2);       \tikz\draw[wall] (0,0.2) -- (0.2, 0);}%       {<abc>}%   } \begin{document} \section{The title includes \protect\abc} \end{document} 
I obtain two separate lines apart from each other. Can this be fixed?

@Caligari sure, you can either use \tikz\draw[wall] (0,0) -- (0.2, 0.2) (0, 0.2) -- (0.2, 0); or you use a tikzpicture environment in the first argument of \texorpdfstring (that's still possible, I just used the sort notation because you drew only a single line).

Thank you, everything works for me now!
